# dotMemory Unmanaged Resources

Tags: c#, .net, dotmemory

I've got a c# `ASP .NET MVC` 5 application that I am profiling with `dotMemory`.  It is a small web application with around maybe 15 controllers, using `EF6/dal`, and `AutoFac/DI`. There are a few other libraries for models/services/etc.

`dotMemory` is showing `600mb` of Unmanaged Memory being allocated, and around 20 MB of memory allocated for `.NET` managed resources.  `dotMemory` won't allow you to explore any of the unmanaged resources.  So how do I identify why my application is using so much unmanaged memory?

Thanks

Comment: You'd have to use a memory profiler/tool that supports unmanaged memory to get more detail.  Every application does have unmanaged memory needs (runtime, Windows application, etc.)  If you're using various libraries/frameworks you can try wiring their use off to see if the #s change to get a better idea of what might be using unmanaged memory.  Or, even just analyze a "hello world" app to compare usage #s.

Comment: I profiled a new mvc 5 project and dotMemory was reporting around 300 mb usage for unmanaged memory. Interesting! I have an older web app running .NET 4.5 and it is a decent sized website.  It only shows 100 mb.